# Windows 8 using 10GB of memory when I sign in

Tags: windows-8, memory

My new company laptop has 16 GB of internal memory but uses 10 GB when I just sign in and the CPU fan is always at 80%. I've not installed anything special yet and no program have started and still it uses 10 GB. When I check the Task Manager and the Resource Monitor the processes does not sum up to more than about 1 GB internal memory use, and the largest process uses 45 MB. Where does the 9 GB dissapear and how can I see what process(es) that is the culprit?

Comment: Please take a screenshot of Task Manager’s memory usage view.

Comment: Try restarting it. You may have a program with a memory leak, and Windows 8 has hybrid shutdown which can cause leaks to persist even if the machine is turned off. Restarting will clear this memory.

Comment: Also check for new drivers in case you have a buggy version with a memory leak.

Comment: Please verify that you have secure boot enabled on the bios. Secure boot enables a a faster boot and a minimal resource consumption.

Comment: post pictures of RAMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: @Ahmad secure boot is just a protection against rootkits but I don't see how that would affect memory usage unless the machine is already compromised.

Comment: RamMap says 8.5 GB is "Driver Locked" - what could this mean?

Comment: "driver locked" is mostly caused by running VM tools like Hyper-V.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Hyper-V is installed but not in use atm, I set the Hyper-V Management Service to start manually and rebooted, and now I have normal memory consumption. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting RAM usage in Windows in detail is not possible with Taskmgr. [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) [displays more details](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx).

High Driver Locked usage is often caused by Virtual Machine tools like hyper-v. So stop/remove Hyper-V.